# Error: QGIS VectorFieldCalc plug-in "Raster_Parameters_Errors: More than one raster band in raster"

Tags: qgis, raster, qgis-plugins, marine, vector-field

I have used VectorFieldCalc plug-in in QGIS several times before, to make maps of marine currents from .nc satellite data. 
Recently, I have tried to redo some of the maps and when I try to calculate the "magnitude" and "orientation" layers, it just says that I have several bands in the same raster and it cannot calculate it. I have tried this in QGIS versions 2.18 and 3 with the same result.
The .nc file that I am working with (available [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5cw30ir3qyl23nx/CUR_20110926_surface.nc?dl=0)) is similar to the ones I worked with before, it contains the current velocities for one particular day at one particular depth. I have also tried downloading the x and y components of the current velocities in different raster files and that doesn't work either.

What am I doing wrong?

[image: Snapshot of VectorFieldCalc error]